# Differential equation solution with Lambert $W$ function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lambert-w

Solving the differential equation: $y'x\log y =1$ we easly find :
$$
y(\log y-1)=\log x +c
$$

I search an explicit solution $y=f(x)$ and [WolframAlpha gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27x%20log%20y%20%20%3D1):
$$
y=\dfrac{\log x+c}{W\left( \dfrac{\log x +c}{e}\right)}
$$

Where $W$ is the [Lambert function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). I know that this function is defined such that $W(ze^z)=z$, but I don't see how this can give the Wolfram result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $y=e^t$, then divide both sides with *e*.

Comment: From your hint I find: $\log y -1=W\left( \dfrac{\log x +c}{e}\right)$ , but how I can find the result of WolfranAlpha?

Comment: Sorry: I see !!! Thank you!